# D3 V4 right click events not registered for dragging

Tags: javascript, d3.js

It seems to me that D3 V4's drag events will no longer register a right click drag. This was not the case in V3.
For example with V4:
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/22994cc97fefaeede0d861e6815a847e
And with V3:
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/a84aeb78fea81e1ad806

Does any one know a work-around for this in order to allow for right-click drag events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied verbatim from the [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#dragging-d3-drag),

> By default, drag behaviors now ignore right-clicks intended for the context menu; use drag.filter to control which events are ignored.

As stated, pass a filter function to [drag.filter](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag/blob/master/README.md#drag_filter) to specify custom events to trigger the drag.