# Better way to implement both left/right drag in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, drag-and-drop

I have been trying to implement left/right drag on the same element in D3.js.

My first attempt was to create separate `d3.drag()` objects for left and right click (by filtering `event.button === 0` and `event.button === 2` respectively, as described by [another stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43482049/d3-v4-right-click-events-not-registered-for-dragging)), then call both on the element. This doesn't work because the second call overwrites the first.

Through trial-and-error I eventually stumbled on the solution below. However, I'm not satisfied with it because it seems very hacky and fragile:

- in `.filter`, I have to use `event.button`, which codes `left,right` as `0,2` whereas
- in `.on(drag, ...)`, I have to use `event.sourceEvent.buttons`, which codes `left,right` as `1,2`

  - Also, for some reason `event.sourceEvent.button` doesn't differentiate between left/right clicks, which is why I went with the plural version.
- `.filter`-ing for both events seems redundant, since that logic is handled in `.on(drag, ...)` already, but if you don't filter first, right-clicking doesn't seem to even trigger an event...

So yeah...  is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

```
let svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 800)
  .attr("height", 800)
  .on("contextmenu", function(event) { event.preventDefault(); }); // prevent right-click spawning context menu

let circle = svg.append("circle").attr("cx", 100).attr("cy", 100).attr("r", 20).attr("fill", "black");

let circleDrag = d3.drag()
  .filter((event) => {
    return event.button === 0 ||  // left-click
           event.button === 2;    // right-click
    })
  .on("drag", function(event) {
        const circ = d3.select(this);
      
        if (event.sourceEvent.buttons === 1) { // left drag
          circ.attr("fill", "blue")
            
        } else if (event.sourceEvent.buttons === 2) { // right drag
          circ.attr("fill", "red")
        }
    
        circ.attr("cx", +circ.attr("cx") + event.dx)
            .attr("cy", +circ.attr("cy") + event.dy);
    });
  
circle.call(circleDrag);
```

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/samtonetto/pen/NWOQwVZ)

Comment: Did you try to use the Mouse Click  with / without Control button instead of different mouse buttons?

Comment: I haven't tried that. Do you mean the solution would be similar?

Comment: Right button is preserved for other uses (like context menu), so it's more convenient to use left button (with or without Ctrl key) instead